# Passing data from a class component to a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

My class component which has the data and adding it to the <PointsLayer component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class EventsMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        console.log("data in events map", data)
....
....
...
                <PointsLayer data={data}/>

export default injectIntl(EventsMap);
```

Trying to receive it inside my PointsLayer component which is a functional component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';
import multipoint from "@arcgis/core/geometry/Multipoint";



const PointsLayer = (props) => {
    const data = this.props.data;
    console.log("data in pointslayer", data);
```

The console.log in my "EventsMap" component shows the data but the console.log in the "PointsLayer" component is undefined. Is is possible to pass data from a class component to a functional component?

Comment: are you returning anything in `render`?

Comment: Yes, I am returning a map component but I omitted that snippet of code. Removing 'this', resolved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can drop the `this` in `PointsLayer`. `this` is not needed to refer to the `prop` in a functional component.

```js
console.log("data in pointslayer", props.data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check `props` directly because you pass data from EventsMap component.

```
// You can find data in props.
console.log(props);
console.log("data in pointslayer", props.data);
```